# Javascript for extracting anchor text from anchor tag

Tags: java, javascript, regex

need help in the following.

In javascript, need to pass a input

as eg:

```
str="<a href=www.google.com>Google</a>"; // this is for example actual input vary
// str is passed as parameter for javascript function
```

The output should retrieve as 'Google'.

I have regex in java and it is working fine in it.

```
String regex = "< a [ ^ > ] * > ( . * ? ) < / a > ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

but in javascript it is not working.

how can I do this in Javascript. Can anyone provide me help for javascript implementation.

Comment: Can you show your code? It is unclear what you are trying to do without seeing your script and HTML.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: anchor.getAttribute("href")

Comment: Can you provide a few other examples so we make sure the regex matches all of them? Are all the variables called "str"? Are all the links formatted exactly like that?

Comment: This looks like a java question.

Comment: I have updated my questin. Hope this explains something clear of my query.

Comment: Why do you have a string of HTML in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont think you would like to use Regex for this. You may try simply like this:-

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>

    var anchor = document.getElementById("myLink");

    alert(anchor.getAttribute("href")); // Extract link

    alert(anchor.innerHTML); // Extract Text
```

[Sample DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ms7bc/3/)

**EDIT:-**(As rightly commented by Patrick Evans)

```
var str = "<a href=www.google.com>Google</a>";
var str1 = document.createElement('str1');
str1.innerHTML = str;
alert(str1.textContent);
alert( str1.innerText);
```

[Sample DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ScacH/3/)

Comment: This is a much better way to do it than regex if that's possible

Comment: this only works because the element is already in the document, OP asks for getting the info from a string.

Comment: Hi, I am currently trying the ways mentioned by you all. Thanks everyone for providing me guidance on this. Shall update which one worked for me soon.

Answer (score 2):

Insert the HTML string into an element, and then just get the text ?

```
var str = "<a href=www.google.com>Google</a>";
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = str;
var txt = div.textContent ? div.textContent : div.innerText;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ScacH/1/)

In jQuery this would be :

```
var str = "<a href=www.google.com>Google</a>";
var txt = $(str).text();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ScacH/2/)

Answer (score 2):

From the suggestions given by you all I got answer and works for me

```
function extractText(){
var anchText = "<a href=www.google.com>Google</a>";
    var str1 = document.createElement('str1');      
    str1.innerHTML = anchText;
    alert("hi "+str1.innerText);
    return anc;
}
```

Thanks everyone for the support

Comment: Awesome, make sure to mark this as the correct answer and if you want to be nice, give everyone who helped an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Just going to take an initial stab at this, I can update this is you add more tests cases or details to your question:

```
\w+="<.*>(.*)</.*>"
```

This matches your provided example, in addition it doesn't matter if:

- the variable name is different
- the tag or contents of the tag wrapping the text are different

What will break this, specifically, is if there are angle brackets inside your html tag, which is possible.

**Note:** It is a much better idea to do this using html as other answers have attempted, I only answered this with a regex because that was what OP asked for. To OP, if you can do this without a regex, do that instead. You should not attempt to parse HTML with javascript when possible, and this regex is not comparable to a full html parser.

Comment: "<a target=\"_blank\" href=<<java class name>>?docId=" + docId + "&cId=" + cId +">" + dName +"</a>" The docId, cId,DName are all dynamic data and is append with the url. This url is passed in href. The anchor tag is passed as input for my question. I have to get 'dName' alone as output. dName is dynamic value. eg: Tom,Scot, Mary etc

Comment: Ok, this regex should work ok. The only thing that will trip it up is if you have angle brackets inside your html tags, which you probably should not have anyway.

Comment: Please see if you can understand now.

Comment: It often helps with regex questions if you can generate a set of strings to test against. That way, I can make sure I understand all the variations and ensure the regex returns correct results in a number of different situations. This particular one is very loose in its requirements, and as noted earlier, should handle everything except angle brackets inside your html tag.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a regex, just parse the string with [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and get the element and then use the DOM object methods/attributes

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var str='<a href='www.google.com'>Google</a>"; 
var dom = parser.parseFromString(str,"text/xml");

//From there use dom like you would use document
var atags = dom.getElementsByTagName("a");
console.log( atags[0].textContent );

//Or
var atag = dom.querySelector("a");
console.log( atag.textContent );

//Or
var atag = dom.childNodes[0];
console.log( atag.textContent );
```

Only catch is DOMParser is not supported in IE lower than 9.

Answer (score -2):

Well, if you're using JQuery this should be an easy task.

I would just create an invisible div and render this anchor () on it. Afterwards you could simply select the anchor and get it's inner text.

```
$('body').append('<div id="invisibleDiv" style="display:none;"></div>'); //create a new invisible div
$('#invisibleDiv').html(str); //Include yours "str" content on the invisible DIV
console.log($('a', '#invisibleDiv').html()); //And this should output the text of any anchor inside that invisible DIV.
```

Remember, to do this way you must have JQuery loaded on your page.

EDIT: Use only if you've already have JQuery on your project, since as stated below, something simple as this should not be a reason for the inclusion of this entire library.

Comment: -1 Something as minor as this would not warrant adding the entire jQuery library to your code. That's a lot of overhead for very little benefit...

Comment: I have to use javascript only. I thought of using regex to extract the anchor text. But is there any other way. I have many restrictions as it is a code developed by other person. I dono who he/she is. That s why.

Comment: @War10ck As i said "if you're using JQuery". I'm not suggesting anyone to include JQuery just for this, but, as today's webApps usually relly on JQuery for lots of things, I'm just providing a JQuery alternative syntax to the other answers that are purely JavaScript.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming that you are using java, from the provided code.

I would recommend you to use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) to extract text inside anchor tag.
Here's a reason why. [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

```
String html = "<a href='www.google.com'>Google</a>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "www.google.com"
String linkText = link.text(); // "Google""

String linkOuterH = link.outerHtml(); 
// "<a href='www.google.com'>Google</a>";
String linkInnerH = link.html(); // "<b>example</b>"
```

Comment: -1 The OP asked for a ***JavaScript*** solution not a ***Java*** solution. Two completely different things...

Comment: ***"how can I do this in Javascript."***

Comment: I'd go with Rahul Tripathi's answer in that case. Take this as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for no help in javascript.